# Honoring previous searches in the next search result in solr

Tags: search, solr, nlp

I am using solr for searching. I wants to improve my search result quality based on previously searched terms. Suppose, I have two products in my index with names `'Jewelry Crystal'`(say it belongs to Group 1) & `'Compound Crystal'`(say it belongs to Group 2). Now, if we query for `'Crystal'`, then both the products will come.

Let say, if I had previously searched for `'Jewelry Ornament'`, then I searches for `'Crystal'`, then I expects that only one result `('Jewelry Crystal')` should come. There is no point of showing `'Compound Crystal'` product to any person looking for `jewelry` type product.

Is there any way in SOLR to honour this kind of behavior or is there any other method to achieve this.

Comment: You would need to specify more in details what you want to achieve; assuming you query a single document field, you could simply add the previous search terms to the current search terms in the new query. The second query would be based on 'jewelry ornament crystals'; documents that match both the previous terms and the current one will tend to be on top.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's nothing built-in in Solr to achive this. What you need for this is some kind of user session, which is not supported by Solr, or a client side storage like a cookie or something for the preceding query.

But to achive the upvote you can use a runtime Boost Query.
Assuming you're using the edismax QueryParser, you can add the following to your Solr query:

```
q=Crystal&boost=bq:(Jewelry Ornament)
```

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#bq_.28Boost_Query.29